# PHP password_verify different results on different servers (algoName unknown)

Tags: php, password-hash

I might be overlooking something, I appreciate kind people who would point that out.

Here is how I test `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`;

```
//$hash = password_hash('test', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
// Which produces; $2y$10$sZQswBo2TYJC4tr578TnnOM4K68W3PEdTAnwZnLFcv50NCFdeWm.m

var_dump(password_verify('test', '$2y$10$sZQswBo2TYJC4tr578TnnOM4K68W3PEdTAnwZnLFcv50NCFdeWm.m'))
// Local: bool(true)
// Remote: bool(false)

print_r( password_get_info( '$2y$10$sZQswBo2TYJC4tr578TnnOM4K68W3PEdTAnwZnLFcv50NCFdeWm.m' );
// Local: Array([algo] => 1, [algoName] => bcrypt, [options] => Array([cost] => 10))
// Remote: Array([algo] => 0, [algoName] => unknown, [options] => Array())
```

Frankly, I produce the hash on the remote machine, it still says algoName is unknown for the hash itself produced.

Comment: what happens if you change your local version to 5.6.36?

Comment: Its is odd everything looks OK, what details are you passing to the `user_authenticate` function, what happens when you pass the hash directly in your return call (not referencing the array)?  If you remove your function and do a simple if statement on it does it pass on both servers?

Comment: @castis, I tried switching to 5.6.30 on local machine, it still works.

Comment: @Yeeooow, I omitted the authenticate function and just did a basic string comparison, but still the same. Works on local machine; the same file copied/pasted, but returning false on remote machines. The only thing I can think of is lack of some sort of libs or external packages; which doesn't make quite sense; because crypt functions work on both machines.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an explicit version difference involved in the `password_verify` itself, according to running a simplified test against a large number of versions: https://3v4l.org/lYGsi My guess is it's something instead to do with the `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` env vars; have you tried dumping out what they contain when run on the remote server?

Comment: @IMSoP, no you're right. There's no version explicit difference. `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW` are populated, I updated the question. Frankly remote server cannot analyze the hash, it says "algoName => unknown". Here lies the issue I gues.

Comment: What Linux distribution (?) exactly are you using? There was some issue in OpenSSL which broke exactly this hashing, and the fix introduced a new `$2y$` algorithm which fixed the issue. That fix was backported on some distros and not on others. Though 5.6.36 *should* have that fix either way IIRC.

Comment: @deceze, I am running `CentOS 6.9 (Final)` and `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips`, but I guess you ment OpenSSL ext of PHP?

Comment: Sorry, not OpenSSL, I misremembered. Here it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Versioning_history; and it should be fixed since 5.3.7…

Comment: Just to simplify the problem (*always* simplify your problems when debugging!) can you remove all the logic with `$_SERVER`, additional function calls, etc, and confirm that `var_dump(password_verify('test', '$2y$10$sZQswBo2TYJC4tr578TnnOM4K68W3PEdTAnwZnLFcv50NCFdeWm.m'));` and `var_dump(password_get_info('$2y$10$sZQswBo2TYJC4tr578TnnOM4K68W3PEdTAnwZnLFcv50NCFdeWm.m'));` return different values on the different servers?

Comment: Well, then my version should not be effected as you have already pointed out. Then why would it say algoName is unknown?

Comment: @IMSoP yes exacly. Those expressions return different results and as I said, `password_get_info()` recognizes as bcrypt on local machine but the remote machine says algoName is unkonwn.

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to reflect that then? i.e. remove all the excess code and just show those two lines, with their exact output on the different servers?

Comment: @IMSoP, I edited the entire question to simplify the situation. (While I had written the excess code for people who would have asked for the "rest of the code"). But it is very clear now I guess.

Comment: @Turab The key to a good question is not that the code is complete in the sense of there's no context missing, but that it's complete to the extent that it *reproduces the problem*. See [mcve]. Obviously there's something else needed to reproduce this, but it must be some detail of the server nobody's thought of yet.

Comment: @IMSoP, I think the problem is clear and obvious. I cannot provide more since we already do not know what is causing PHP not knowing the algorhtym of the hash itself procuded. If I could reproduce the error, I could already do it on my local machine. The problem is already the reason behind it; we don't know how it is produced. Isn't it clear? Thanks for your time by the way.

Comment: Stab into the dark: your server needs some additional package installed? `apt-get install php5-bcrypt` or whatever the correct incantation is for CentOS?

Comment: @Turab What is the output of `var_dump($s='test', $h=password_hash($s, PASSWORD_BCRYPT), password_verify($s, $h), password_get_info($h));`when you run it on your remote host? Please edit your question to include the output of this `var_dump()` line.